# How to call API in laravel which include the OAuth key and secret

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I want to call external API from `laravel HttpClient`. I'm  not understanding how to pass the following authorization keys of `OAuth 1.0`.

```
1. Signature Method
2. Consumer Key
3. Consumer Secret
4. Access Token
5. Token Secret
6. Version
7. Realm
```

is this the right way?

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Signature Method' => 'Signature Method',
    'Consumer Key' => 'Consumer Key'
])->post('http://test.com/users', [
    'name' => 'Taylor',
]);
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: The Laravel HTTP client is essentially a wrapper around Guzzle so you could use [guzzle/oauth-subscriber](https://github.com/guzzle/oauth-subscriber) assuming you already went through the oauth process and got the user token and secret

Comment: Thanks for link. I will go through the documentation.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65225865/296555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use laravels own HTTP client or you can also use CURL
the simplest workaround is you can simply call the request in the Postman and then there is a section in postman where you can find the request c[image]ode
there you can simply copy the request code and post it.

Comment: You are always welcome and I am glad I could help you